# Can't run licensed software using dongle, says NetBIOS is disabled

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a licensed dongle for Oxford Instrument Channel 5 software, but the program does not run when the dongle is inserted into the USB port (Windows 7). It says NetBIOS is disabled (see image).

[image]

Comment: The urgency of your problem is irrelevant here. If you need urgent or time critical support then you should be contacting the company that supplied you the hardware or software.

Comment: Emailed them, but no response. They are located overseas from the country I am residing.

Comment: Did you turn on file and printer sharing? Is network discovery turned on? Did you enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP in your IPv4 configuration?

Comment: Just checked, NetBIOS is enabled over TCP/IP and sharing/discovery is turned on. The PC is not connected to a network, should I plug in a Ethernet cable?

Comment: I wonder why it would even need NetBIOS. That software has nothing to do with networking does it?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with networking. From the error prompt, it seems it is required for licensing.

Comment: Maybe disabling the firewall will help.

Comment: Symantec endpoint protection, I have disabled the firewall but still the same.

Comment: You could use [process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what that software is doing and what exactly it is trying to access on the network. Alternatively [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) could also help.

Comment: "HASP License Manager" is linking the dongle and the Channel 5 software. My gut feeling is something wrong with HASP.